# Firestore Query result not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore document setup like that:

```
public class Item {
  String name;
  Map<String, Boolean> testMap;

}
```

I have all the getters and empty consturctor, adding, updating Firestore documents work.

When i put value into the map it looks like this:

```
testMap: { 
testValue: true }
```

but then when i try to query that value with code below, `for()` loop doesn't work. I get `I/Task: Successful` log, but `I/TestLog: TestLog`  is not showing and code below it doesn't work either

```
mColRef.whereEqualTo("testMap.testValue", true)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                    if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.i("Task", "Successful");


                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                            Log.i("TestLog", "TestLog");

                            Log.i("ItemName:", document.getString("name");

                        }

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(FirebaseTest.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }
            });
```

I'm really confused, i pretty much followed the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays), but i can't get the result

Comment: You should log the result of `task.getResult()`

Comment: Please check if the data is properly fetched by added a log as suggested in the above comment.

Comment: Ok, turns out I'm just dumb, i logged the size of result and it returned 0, thanks for help guys, I'll post the whole answer below for better visibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i got it to work and it turns out it was my  stupid mistake in query.

I updated the `testMap`with different value than i provided here in question, an email to be exact, because I thought it totally doesn't make any difference. Turns out it does. When i queried for the result i used `mColRef.whereEqualTo("testMap.email@email.com", true)` and there's that `.`(dot) inside email address. The dot can't be used as value in query because it's used to separate nested objects from all of the others in databas, so the query probably looked for object named `com` inside `email` map